# Composer update not working because of a missing class in config/app.php?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

Something strange happened to me today : a collegue changed something in `config/app.php` , so that a different class is used as a service provider instead of the original one.

The code for this new class is in a package that was added to `composer.json`.

I updated from SVN and got both new files, but then `composer update` didn't work, because this somehow uses the `config/app.php` , which was broken, because it didn't know the class, which of course would only be in `vendor` AFTER `composer update` !

So my question is : why would `composer update` need anything that is in `config/app.php` ?  And how to prevent something like this in the future?

Comment: Where you trying to install a new package via `composer update`? If so, then you should be running `composer install`.

Comment: yes, but this failed, because of the missing class!

Comment: Did `composer install`  or `composer update` fail? I can see `composer update` failing because of `pre-update-cmd` scripts being run which would affect the update process, but since you said you're installing a new package, then you should use `install`.

Comment: `composer update` failed, we use a version control system, so every developer does not have to install packages themselves, but can simply do an `composer update` after getting the new updates from the vcs.  What are those `pre-update-cmd` scripts you're talking about?

Comment: Please see the comment I posted for you on @Chris's answer. It explains why `update` failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your `config/app.php` file and comment out the provider which was added by your colleague. Run `composer update` and then uncomment it, maybe `php artisan optimize` too and then you should be good to go.

**EDIT:** When a new package has been added by someone else, you need to install it. You only need to run `composer update` when you want to update all of your packages to their latest versions, or the framework.

Comment: Yeah I figured that out myself too, but isn't composer supposed to be able to run independently from your app ?  Luckily the original class was not deleted but commented out, so I could find the solution, but I think it's a design error to not be able to use composer update, when something has changed in config/app.php

Comment: Composer install should have worked bud. Laravel has special configurations for composer update that run some additional scripts via artisan, which is why you get the error when you try to update.

Comment: @Dylan it's not a design error at all. Update is suppose to update existing packages, and since you in your `config/app.php` you have references to a class which is not installed yet you'll get errors because [before the update process it will run `php artisan clear-compiled`](http://bit.ly/1SxQkJt), and `artisan` **is** part of Laravel, and will throw errors because of those broken references. If you use `install` to install new packages that should not happen because [that clear compile command is run after the install](http://bit.ly/1QBzKWP) when the referenced class is present.

Comment: Well IMO that is a design error. I should be able to do a `composer update` no matter what. I was not aware of the `artisan` stuff in `composer.json` Why does Laravel even try to affect something generic as `composer` ??

Comment: @Dylan You're using the wrong command. When a colleague updates composer.json/lock and you pull it down, you need to use `composer install` not update.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the semantic difference between update and install. If a package is in `vendor` then the correct actions is update, if it's not the correct action is `install`. You said it yourself, a **new** package was added to `composer.json`, and logically new packages need to be installed, because you can't update something that is not installed yet :).

Comment: Ok, that makes sense... but how should I know that I should do an `composer install` instead of `composer update` then ?  I update using VCS and nothing works anymore, isn't that a bit inconvenient in your opinion?

Comment: @Dylan Distinguishing between the right command is easy. If you have new packages added in the `composer.json` require list then you should use `install` to install them. `composer update` should only be used when you want to update existing composer packages to newer versions. It's not inconvenient at all. I think you might be confusing the idea of updating your project files to the latest state (from the version control server), with the composer action of updating package versions.

Comment: Also should add that you need to composer install **before** you update your config/app to avoid problems like this in the future